# Does RUAG Space recover and reuse Ariane 5 and Atlas V payload fairings after splashdown?

Tags: reuse, fairings, ariane, atlas-v, ruag-space

[RUAG Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RUAG_Space) is the company that manufactures payload fairings for the Ariane, Vega, Atlas V (500 series) and the upcoming Vulcan.

Back when Spacex started trying to catch the fairing without it hitting the water, I recall someone mentioning that their competitors Ariane 5 and Atlas V use fairings from a company that designs them to be recoverable after splashdown, and apparently reusable (maybe partially).

I believe I saw that said in an article or response concerning [this tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1069679948103847939) by Elon.

Now that I actually search for it, I can't find a single mention of RUAG Space or any of those rockets recovering their fairings.

**Does RUAG Space recover (and reuse?) their fairings after splashdown?**

Comment: "No they don't recover them at all and never considered doing so" is an acceptable answer if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't.

Here is the RUAG Space page for fairings:

https://www.ruag.com/en/products-services/space/launchers/launchers

As we can see, no mention of reusability. Also no mentions it's planned in future. As all the other fairing manufacturers in the world except of SpaceX, they produce new fairings for every launch.

RUAG fairings are not recovered, they land in the ocean, most probably destroyed by the atmosphere because they don't have attitude-keeping mechanisms.

In my opinion, even without the link above - the lack of information about RUAG fairings recovery is enough. :) From common sence and knowledge of how corporations and PR work. RUAG would surely mention it loudly if they did. "Our rival SpaceX reuses fairings - we reuse too!"